# how to disable action method on a button click programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I am developing a simple quiz game in which if a button is clicked then the player can have two chances to give answer. If first choice is right, then buttonClicked action will performed. If it is wrong then player can have second chance to give the answer. if it is correct, buttonClicked will performed otherwise game over.

please guide me how to perform this .. Any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: hide the button when you dont want any input from the button.

Comment: i dont want to hide button,it should be visible

Comment: add a counter in your app and once it reaches 2 do not perform any task.

Answer (score 3):

UIControll has [property enabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl).

> If the enabled state is NO, the control ignores touch events ...

Comment: If it is not enabled, how it will check right answer is selected or not?

Comment: When and which button do you want to disable? Please add sample of your code or try to explain your problem more.